# How to access image from media library to theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Wordpress. In the theme, there is banner slider in the header. I have uploaded images from Media Library. Now, I want to use those images in my header's banner slider.

How can I access it from the Appearance->Them Editor->header.php ?

Thank you,
Trupti

Comment: what theme are you using?

Comment: It is customized theme. How does it matter?